# Scala Range.Double missing last element

Tags: scala, floating-point, double, range

I am trying to create a list of `numBins` numbers evenly spaced in the range [`lower`,`upper`). Of course, there are floating point issues and this approach is not the best. The result of using `Range.Double`, however, surprises me as the element missing is not close to the upper bound at all.

Setup:

```
val lower = -1d
val upper = 1d
val numBins = 11
val step = (upper-lower)/numBins   // step = 0.18181818181818182
```

Problem:

```
scala>   Range.Double(lower, upper, step)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange[Double] = NumericRange(-1.0, -0.8181818181818182, -0.6363636363636364, -0.45454545454545453, -0.2727272727272727, -0.0909090909090909, 0.09090909090909093, 0.27272727272727276, 0.4545454545454546, 0.6363636363636364)
```

Issue: The list seems to be one element short. 0.8181818181818183 is one step further, and is less than 1.

Workaround:

```
Scala>   for (bin <- 0 until numBins) yield lower + bin * step
res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Double] = Vector(-1.0, -0.8181818181818181, -0.6363636363636364, -0.4545454545454546, -0.2727272727272727, -0.09090909090909083, 0.09090909090909083, 0.2727272727272727, 0.4545454545454546, 0.6363636363636365, 0.8181818181818183)
```

This result now contains the expected number of elements, including 0.818181..

Comment: Works fine for me (scala 2.11.8). What version of scala are you running?

Comment: I just pasted your code into my REPL (Scala 2.10.3...) and it works as expected - I do get `0.8181818181818182`.

Comment: version: Scala version 2.11.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0)

Comment: Scala version 2.13.2. Is Range.Double removed? Can someone please suggest alternate API

Answer (score 0):

I think the root cause of your problem is some features in implementation of `toString` for `NumericRange`

```
217  override def toString() = { 
218     val endStr = if (length > Range.MAX_PRINT) ", ... )" else ")" 
219     take(Range.MAX_PRINT).mkString("NumericRange(", ", ", endStr) 
220   }
```

**UPD:** It's not about `toString`. Some other methods like `map` and `foreach` cut last elements from returned collection.

Anyway by checking `size` of collection you've got - you'll find out - all elements are there.

What you've done in your workaround example - is used different underlying datatype.

Comment: Thanks, on further inspection: With `.size` I get 12 elements. `.last` gives `1d`. `for (i <- rng) println(i)` gives the same elements as the toString. Indexing (though apply) allows recall of the 9th element (0.636363..) but not the missing 10th (0.818181..)

Comment: Try to check `.tail`

Comment: Tail has all the elements. How interesting. How come these methods miss elements? This seems counter-intuitive and isn't it against the documentation?

Comment: I would suggest you to avoid `Range.Double`. There are some bugs in this functionality. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8782

Comment: Also there are numerous "TODO" marks in code related to "NumericRange" class. You'd better to use `lower to upper by step` in your sample. It works exactly as you need.